# Plymouth taking a lot of time during boot

Tags: boot, plymouth, boot-time

```
 $ systemd-analyze blame

     3min 19.728s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     19.248s dev-sda4.device
     13.448s systemd-udevd.service
      6.593s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.702s snapd.service
      4.262s networking.service
      3.733s fwupd.service
      3.149s irqbalance.service
      2.981s apport.service
      2.484s NetworkManager.service
      2.338s grub-common.service
      2.322s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.321s ondemand.service
      2.240s accounts-daemon.service
      1.518s keyboard-setup.service
      1.246s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.212s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.165s apparmor.service
      1.065s systemd-modules-load.service
       966ms systemd-journald.service
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `plymouth` during your boot up process and display progress messages by using:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line containing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and remove `quiet splash` between the double quotes. If you have additional parameters leave them as is.

Save the file and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot and watch the messages that appear for any clues on what is causing delays.

After boot completes run:

```
systemd-analze blame
```

once more and report back with the results.